# Is there a contradiction between the continuity equation and Poiseuilles Law?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, viscosity

The continuity equation states that flow rate should be conserved in different areas of a pipe:

$$Q = v_1 A_1 = v_2 A_2 = v\pi r^2$$

We can see from this equation that **velocity and pipe radius are inversely proportional**. If radius is doubled, velocity of flow is quartered.

Another way I was taught to describe flow rate is through Poiseuilles Law:

$$Q = \frac{\pi r^4\Delta P}{8\eta L}$$

So if I were to plug in the continuity equations definition of flow rate into Poiseuilles Law:

$$vA = v\pi r^2= \frac{\pi r^4\Delta P}{8\eta L} $$

Therefore:

$$v =  \frac{ r^2\Delta P}{8\eta L}$$

Now in this case, **the velocity is proportional to the radius of the pipe**. If the radius is doubled, then velocity is qaudrupled.

What am I misunderstanding here? I would prefer a conceptual explanation because I feel that these equations are probably used with different assumptions/in different contexts.

Comment: The first equation is for non viscous flow while poiseuilles law is for viscous flow of water in a cylindrical pipe.

Comment: You're misunderstanding Hagen-Poiseuille. HP takes pressure into account, but you don't seem to.

Answer (score 1):

When you write down $Q = vA$, it's implicit that the velocity profile is uniform over the cross-section A (and purely perpendicular to it).

In general,

$$Q = \int \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{A}$$

This no longer implies that $v \propto \frac{1}{R^2}$.

If we assume $\mathbf{v}$ has purely radial dependence and is aligned with $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{A}$ as in Poiseuille flow, then we have:

$$Q = 2\pi \int_0^R v(r) r \mathrm{d}r$$

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed volumetric throughput rate Q, $\Delta P$ decreases as $r^4$, so v decreases as $r^2$, exactly what you would expect from the continuity equation.